# How to store copy of document into a variable after deleting that document with findByIdAndDelete?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to delete a document but also need to have a copy of the document but something is not working in my code:

```
const deletedPlace= await Place.findByIdAndDelete(placeId);
console.log(deletedPlace);
```

This code returns null.
Can someone tell me what i have to do so that `deletedPlace` stores the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around using the same technique as @sebastian-ruehmann.

```
let deletedPlace;
await Place.findByIdAndDelete(placeId,(err,doc)=>{deletedPlace=doc});
console.log(deletedPlace);
```

Answer (score 2):

You search for `Place.findByIdAndRemove(placeId, deletedPlace => {})`

Comment: thanks, i found a similar solution appreciate your help though.